# initialize float-type array using memset

Tags: c, memset

I have a pointer `float *ptr`, after dynamic allocation with length `n`, I want to initialize this array with zero or one, so I use `memset(ptr,0,n*sizeof(float))` or `memset(ptr,1,n*sizeof(float))`. Is this legal? Because the second argument of `memset` is int-type, I'm afraid it cannot be applied to float-type.

Comment: That argument is the value to set each byte to, not each 32-bit word. `0x0` is float zero, but `0x01010101` isn't 1, it's ~2.3*10**-38

Comment: So initialize with 0 values is okay, while 1 is dangerous?

Comment: no they're both safe and defined; it's just that you can't see an array of floats to 1 with memset; the interface doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3):

> memset(ptr,1,n*sizeof(float)). Is this legal?

No, not to set the value of the `float` to `1.0f` as the encoding of a `float` in not the bytes `1,1,1,1` [@James Picone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053705/initialize-float-type-array-using-memset/51054337#comment89098393_51053705)

---

`memset(ptr,0,n*sizeof(float))` or better `memset(ptr, 0, sizeof *ptr * n)` will set every byte to 0. This is certainly the encoding for a `float` `0.0f`.

To set every element of a  `float` array to `1.0f` or any value, simply  use a loop.

```
float init_value = 1.0f;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; n++) {
   ptr[i] = init_value;
}
```

Comment: All bits zero is `0.0f` in IEEE754, however the standard doesn't mandate such a representation

Answer (score 1):

Initializing floats to all-bytes-zero is OK (it will produce float 0.0).  But all-bytes-1 is not reasonable, because it will produce a "garbage" value (but the same value every time).